# How to count the number of rows with specific data in mssql

Tags: sql-server, count

I have the following table:

Items:

```
ID     Type     StockExists  
01     Cellphone   T
02     Cellphone   F
03     Apparrel    T
```

I want to `count the number of items` with existing stocks, i.e., the number of rows with `StockExists='T'`. I was performing the query as;

```
Select count(StockExists) 
From [Items] where StockExists='T'
```

but it is always returning 1. What is the right way to do it?

**Edit:**

Also, how to perform another such Count operation and add them together in one row, for example,

```
Select count(StockExists) 
From [Items] where StockExists='T'` and `Select count(Type) 
From [Items] where Type='Cellphone'` ?
```

Comment: Your query looks fine [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c0e44/2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) As ExistCount 
FROM 
    dbo.Items
WHERE
    StockExists='T'
```

So your query should work.

Result:

```
EXISTCOUNT
    2
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c0e44/1/0)

**Update**

> How to perform another such Count operation and add them together in
>   one row, for example, Select count(StockExists) From [Items] where
>   StockExists='T' and Select count(Type) From [Items] where
>   Type='Cellphone' ?

You can use `SUM` with `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
  ExistCount = SUM(CASE WHEN StockExists='T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ,
  CellphoneCount = SUM(CASE WHEN Type='Cellphone' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM 
    dbo.Items
```

Result:

```
EXISTCOUNT    CELLPHONECOUNT
    2               2
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c0e44/7/0)

Comment: thanks, it is working now. What can I do to get another count on the same table as the previous one with some different criteria and merge the two counts in a single row in different columns?

Answer (score 1):

Select Sum(Case when field = 'this' then 1 else 0 end) as Total
from YourTable

Answer (score 0):

> When using CASE WHEN better to use NULL than 0 in ELSE case like below

```
 SELECT 
      ExistCount = SUM(CASE WHEN StockExists='T' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) ,
      TotalCount = COUNT(ID) 
    FROM 
        dbo.Items
```